# Complex redirect in vue router

Tags: javascript, regex, vue-router

I am using vue-router on a multipage app; we are adding history mode because our requirements insist our urls not contain special characters (#) and want to ensure from within our frontend code that we are always prepending our clientside routes with `/v/`. (to avoid having to update all our routes in the whole app, and to centralize this functionality).

I want to add a route similar to:

```
routes: [
    // add `v/` to paths that don't start with `v/`
    { 
      path: `(^\/(?!v))*`, 
      redirect: to => `/v/${to}` 
    },
]
```

Based on using regex inside [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#custom-matching-parameters), but I'm not entirely clear from their documentation how to properly pass in a whole route as a regex (or is it possible?), especially without getting caught in a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use 2 redirects to achieve what I needed (in this case falling back to '/' as a sort of 404.

```
// Fallback to baseRoute for prefixed unmatched routes
{ path: `${prefix}/*`, redirect: '/' },
// Fallback to baseRoute for unprefixed, unmatched routes (try again with prefix)
{ path: `*`, redirect: to => prefix + to.path }
```

(An interesting gotcha is that in a redirect function the `to` value remains unchanged if you get redirected, so I originally had an infinite loop. with `to => to.path.startsWith(prefix) ? '/' : prefix + to.path`)